# Matching partially string on url string in python3

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match or find coincidence a string in python with regex method `re.search()` without lucky

this is my code:

```
import re

request_path = '/colpos/papanicolaou2/124579/1254'
urls = ['/colpos/prescription', '/colpos/transfer', '/colpos/papanicolaou2', '/colpos/biopsia']

for url in urls:
    c_url = re.compile(url)
    result = re.search(c_url, request_path)
    if isinstance(result, re.Match):
        allowed_url = url
        break

print(allowed_url) # must be /colpos/papanicolau2
```

what I want to happen?, if url is in request_path (in this case partially) I expect that result been re.Match object instance not None.

how can I achive this?, is any better way to know if my request_path is in urls?

the code mentioned above only works if url and request_path contains exactly the same, I dont want that. How should I use `re.search()` in python to achive this?

thank you

Comment: Just tried out your code, it [prints](https://tio.run/##ZY/RasMwDEXf/RWCPSSB0rCsZXTQT9gXjFEUzyFiju1JMmNfnznNWDOmBwvfe6xrpS8dY3iYZ5pSZAV2xrD7yE70klBHOEPV2uhTlDZhwkDlgjF37X13OD6eSjseKpPZS0Ffbiw7sUxJKYZqd5uhjEEGx1vtz9yt0VNMQli9GjNEhhICFJYmTwZK2csincun9zZOibyri9BcvZKfva6mOGQ71ld8B9v1VpYGIKEgisG6en25cPtnVDs2a9hS6H38dG8/seX8dXp2@G5MYgpab7AG7mDKotA7@L9v7ub5Gw) `/colpos/papanicolaou2`

Comment: I am not sure what the `re.Match` class is exactly (at least in python 3.6.9 there is no class with that exact name - a match seems to be an instance of `<class '_sre.SRE_Match'>`), so I changed the condition simply to `if result:` (because it is `None` on no match), but apart from that, the code seems okay.

Comment: holysht! yes you right. I have tested the code on new jupyter file and it works, wtf, don't know what the hell is going on, I am a newbie on python and jupyter, sorry for the inconvenience. case closed

Comment: @alaniwi when I ask if isinstance(result, re.Match) I'm refering to this: <re.Match object; span=(0, 20), match='/colpos/papanicolau2'> <class 're.Match'> executing print(result, type(result)) before asking if is instance

Comment: @CarlosGómez It seems maybe that for whatever reason, the exact type of object returned on a match may not be portable between different python implementations, but you can safely and portably just do `if result:` because it will be some kind of value that is treated as true, as opposed to `None`. Anyway, it seems that this was not the issue here, just some kind of confusion happened.

Answer (score 1):

I tried checking it with the "in" keyword instead of using re module. I think it is simpler and more readable.

```
request_path = '/colpos/papanicolaou2/124579/1254'
urls = ['/colpos/prescription', '/colpos/transfer', '/colpos/papanicolaou2', '/colpos/biopsia']
allowed_urls = []

for url in urls:
    if url in request_path:
        allowed_urls.append(url)

print(allowed_urls) # this contains '/colpos/papanicolaou2' like you wanted
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you just got 2 fixed (real) parts for your request_path, you could the following (no loops, no regex - just Python):

```
/colpos/papanicolaou2/124579/1254
/part_1/part_2       /param1/param2/...
```

Code:

```
urls = ['colpos/prescription', 'colpos/transfer', 'colpos/papanicolaou2', 'colpos/biopsia']
request_path = "/colpos/papanicolaou2/124579/1254"
p1, p2, params = request_path[1:].split('/', 2)

if '/'.join([p1, p2]).lower() not in urls:
    #raise Error(404)
    print("url not found")
```

Note: You would need to make it more stable for production usage :)